# Запись в файл в bash

Tags: файлы, bash, linux

Есть число a, прочитанное из предпоследней строки 
a=$(tail -n 2 1.txt | head -n 1).
Это число a увеличивается на некоторое число b - a=$((a + b)). Как записать полученное значение a в этот же файл на предпоследнюю строку?

Comment: В этот же файл на bash не получится. Делайте новый (временный), а потом mv его в старый.

Comment: avp можно поподробнее и что такое mv? Я так понял, что необходимо прочитать весь старый файл построчно, записать его в новый (каким образом это делается не знаю) с изменением на предпоследней строке и наверно как-то перенести его в старый.

Comment: open("file", O_RDONLY)                  = 3
    open("./sedfJxyvQ", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
    read(3, "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n", 4096) = 21
    write(4, "line 1\n", 7)                 = 7
    write(4, "line 2\n", 7)                 = 7
    read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
    write(4, "new line\n", 9)               = 9
    write(4, "line 3\n", 7)                 = 7
    read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    close(4)                                = 0
    rename("./sedfJxyvQ", "file")           = 0

Comment: можно прокомментитировать последнюю программу

Comment: Это не программа, это логи системных вызовов при помощи [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace).

    strace sed -i "\$i$a" file

Answer (score 3):

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), вы недооцениваете bash :)

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ a="new line"
$ sed -i "\$i$a" file # $ - последняя строка; i - вставка строки в начало шаблона
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
new line
line 3
```

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, это не **bash** а **sed**. Кстати, интересно, а он редактирует файл по месту или перезаписывает его ? Проверить можно, посмотрев на inode (ls -i).

Comment: @avp, не придирайтесь к словам. С тем же успехом то же самое можно сказать, например, про `cat`. Так уж устроено shell-программирование - на вызове внешних утилит. Так что все приложения входящие в GNU вполне можно считать средствами языка.

PS `sed -i` работает именно так, как вы написали: пишет во временный файл, а затем подменяет его. Без `-i` просто пишет в stdout. Кстати, это наглядно можно посмотреть через `strace`

Comment: И в первой программе i - это вставка в конец шаблона?

Comment: [Да](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).